# Query optimization not using index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

I'm running into performance issues with Sql Server 2008 R2, which I've narrowed down to the query optimizer (I think!). I'm looking for a definitive "why does this happen, or is it a bug?".

For sake of discussion I'll use this example, but the same problem has been seen across multiple sprocs with the same scenario.
We have a table containing payment methods; key fields are PaymentMethodId and UserId.
PaymentMethodId is an int, and the PK; UserId is a nvarchar(255) with a non-clustered index.

The query is similar to the following:

Sproc params worth mentioning:
@id int = null
@userId nvarchar(255) = null
There is an if statement at the beginning of the sproc to disallow both parameters being null.

```
select * from PaymentMethods (nolock) pm
where (@userId is null or @userId = pm.UserId)
  and (@id is null or @id = pm.PaymentMethodId)
```

In the case where @userId is null, I would expect the optimizer to detect the first where clause as always true; if @userId is NOT null, I would expect it to use the index on UserId.
I have the same expectations for @id.

What we're seeing, is that regardless of input values the database is electing to do a full table scan.
While this is concerning on its own, it gets more interesting.

When updating the query where clause to equivalent of below, it is using the indecies correctly.

```
select * from PaymentMethods (nolock) pm
where ((@userId is null and pm.UserId is null) OR @userId = pm.UserId)
  and (@id is null or @id = pm.PaymentMethodId)
```

What is going on? Why is "@userId is null" being considered for every record, (or is it?) Or is the real issue sitting in front of they keyboard?!

Comment: Could be because (a) your table is small (small number of rows), or (b) because you're using `SELECT *` there's no way the index can "cover" the query, so a lot of key lookups would be necessary and ultimately that would be more expensive than just doing a full table scan.

Comment: There are 11.3 million records in the table, and the actual query does call fields by name instead of *.

Comment: Please post a snapshot of the query plan.  Do you have the table definition and sample data.  A few records.

Comment: OK, so the table isn't small - question still is: (a) does the `WHERE` clause filter "enough" or are you getting half those rows back? And (b) are **all** those columns in your `SELECT` part of the index (index or included column) - otherwise my comment still applies about having to do too many key lookups

Comment: @mark_s, the where clause will filter to payment methods owned by a user (< 10 records) or a single payment method (1 record).
All the columns in my select statement are definitely NOT part of an index. The where clause however, is sufficient to bring the set down to a small number of records.

Comment: See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). This kind of "catch all" query should be avoided unless you want to use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a number of reasons why your sp is slow. For instance, stored procedures create a plan depending on the values for the parameters when you first run that sp. This means that you get the same plan even when the new values may return a completely different result set, one that could benefit from another plan. You could try using dynamic SQL or run the sp with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` so the optimizer can create another execution plan. This is one example:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE dbo.Test @userid INT, @id INT
AS

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @sql = N'SELECT * 
             FROM PaymentMethods pm
             WHERE 1 = 1'

SET @sql =  @sql + 
            CASE 
                WHEN @userid IS NOT NULL THEN N' AND pm.UserId = @userid '
                ELSE N'' 
            END +
            CASE 
                WHEN @id IS NOT NULL THEN N' AND pm.PaymentMethodId = @id '
                ELSE N'' 
            END 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@userid INT, @id INT', @userid, @id;
```

Comment: I don't like dynamic sql as a solution, but your comments regarding plan creation was what I was looking for. Thank you.
We've decided to use an if statement and separate queries for now.